# How to dynamically create an html <dialog> element using Javascript that displays hidden info

Tags: javascript

I've been tasked to create 5 car objects using a constructor function. Each object should have basic information about a car as properties and must also include a showMore() method that displays a dialog that displays more details about a car. Whenever a user clicks on a button, the showMore() method should be called and all the information about the car, including the
registration number, price etc should be displayed.
So I've written the code for this task, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong regarding the code for the dialog.

```js
//constructor function
function Car(brand,model,colour,regNumber, carsPicture,price){
    this.brand = brand;
    this.model = model;
    this.colour = colour;
    this.regNumber = regNumber;
    this.imageSrc = carsPicture;
    this.price = price;
    this.showMore = function(){
        document.querySelector(".featured-cars");
        let dialog = document.createElement("dialog");
        dialog.classList.add("dialog-box");
        let paragraph = document.createElement("p");
        paragraph.classList.add("showMore-info");
        paragraph.innerHTML =  
        "Brand: " + this.brand +
        "Modal: " + this.model +
        "Colour: " + this.colour +
        "Reg.Number: " + this.regNumber;
        let perchase = document.createElement("button");
        perchase.innerHTML= "Buy";

    };
    
};
let car1 = new Car(
    "Mercedes",
    "AMG",
    "Metalic",
    "CA227788",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/112460/pexels-photo-112460.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    "R 120 000"
);
let car2 = new Car(
    "Jeep",
    "Cherokee SUV",
    "White",
    "234 567 GP",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/119435/pexels-photo-119435.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    "R 200 000"
);
let car3 = new Car(
    "Audi",
    "Coupe",
    "Yellow",
    "123456 KZN",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1149831/pexels-photo-1149831.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    "R 154 897"
);
let car4 = new Car(
    "BMW",
    "4 series Coupe",
    "Blue",
    "246810 EC",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
     "R 200 000"
);
let car5 = new Car(
    "Pontiac",
    "Sedan",
    "Yellow",
    "321 Ready WP",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/4502385/pexels-photo-4502385.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    "R 300 000"
);
let theCars = [car1,car2,car3,car4,car5];
let carSales = {};
carSales.addCars = function(){
    theCars.forEach(function (car4sale){
        let div = document.querySelector(".featured-cars");
        let carImg = document.createElement("img");
        carImg.classList.add("carImages");
        carImg.src = car4sale.imageSrc;
        carImg.alt = car4sale.colour+ " " + car4sale.brand;
        

        let btnShowmore = document.createElement("button");
        btnShowmore.classList.add("viewMoreBtn");
        btnShowmore.innerHTML = "View More";
        btnShowmore.addEventListener("click", function() {
            car4sale.showMore();
        });
        
        let carPrice = document.createElement("h2");
        carPrice.classList.add("carPrice");
        carPrice.innerHTML = car4sale.price;

        let carColorAndBrnad = document.createElement("h3");
        carColorAndBrnad.classList.add("color-and-brand");
        carColorAndBrnad.innerHTML = car4sale.colour+ " " +car4sale.brand;

        let carinfo = document.createElement("div");
        carinfo.classList.add("carInfo");
        carinfo.classList.add("overlay");
        carinfo.appendChild (carPrice);
        carinfo.appendChild(carColorAndBrnad);
        carinfo.appendChild(btnShowmore);

        div.appendChild(carImg);
        div.appendChild(carinfo);
    });
};
carSales.addCars();
```

```html
<div class="featured-cars"></div>
```

Comment: See how you've used `appendChild` to add children to their parents? Now you need to add the `dialog` element to the document somewhere. Usually they're added to the `body` (referred to as `document.body`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a study of this

I move the event handler to the container (that  is called delegation) and save the index of the car in the button

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".featured-cars");
//constructor function
function Car(brand, model, colour, regNumber, carsPicture, price) {
  this.brand = brand;
  this.model = model;
  this.colour = colour;
  this.regNumber = regNumber;
  this.imageSrc = carsPicture;
  this.price = price;
};
let theCars = [new Car( "Mercedes", "AMG", "Metalic", "CA227788", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/112460/pexels-photo-112460.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500", "R 120 000" ), new Car( "Jeep", "Cherokee SUV", "White", "234 567 GP", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/119435/pexels-photo-119435.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500", "R 200 000" ), new Car( "Audi", "Coupe", "Yellow", "123456 KZN", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1149831/pexels-photo-1149831.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500", "R 154 897" ), new Car( "BMW", "4 series Coupe", "Blue", "246810 EC", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500", "R 200 000" ), new Car( "Pontiac", "Sedan", "Yellow", "321 Ready WP", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/4502385/pexels-photo-4502385.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500", "R 300 000" ) ];

let carSales = {};
carSales.addCars = function() {
  theCars.forEach(function(car4sale, i) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    let carImg = document.createElement("img");
    carImg.classList.add("carImages");
    carImg.src = car4sale.imageSrc;
    carImg.alt = car4sale.colour + " " + car4sale.brand;
    let btnShowmore = document.createElement("button");
    btnShowmore.classList.add("viewMoreBtn");
    btnShowmore.innerHTML = "View More";
    btnShowmore.dataset.idx = i;
    let carPrice = document.createElement("h2");
    carPrice.classList.add("carPrice");
    carPrice.innerHTML = car4sale.price;

    let carColorAndBrnad = document.createElement("h3");
    carColorAndBrnad.classList.add("color-and-brand");
    carColorAndBrnad.innerHTML = car4sale.colour + " " + car4sale.brand;

    let carinfo = document.createElement("div");
    carinfo.classList.add("carInfo");
    carinfo.classList.add("overlay");
    carinfo.appendChild(carPrice);
    carinfo.appendChild(carColorAndBrnad);
    carinfo.appendChild(btnShowmore);

    div.appendChild(carImg);
    div.appendChild(carinfo);
    container.appendChild(div);
  });
};
carSales.addCars();

container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("viewMoreBtn")) {
    const parent = tgt.closest("div")
    const idx = tgt.dataset.idx;
    let dialog = document.createElement("dialog");
    dialog.classList.add("dialog-box");
    let close = document.createElement("button")
    close.addEventListener("click",function() { this.closest("dialog").close() })
    close.innerHTML = "X"
    dialog.appendChild(close)
    let paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    paragraph.classList.add("showMore-info");
    paragraph.innerHTML =
      "Brand: " + theCars[idx].brand +
      "Model: " + theCars[idx].model +
      "Colour: " + theCars[idx].colour +
      "Reg.Number: " + theCars[idx].regNumber;
    let purchase = document.createElement("button");
    purchase.innerHTML = "Buy";
    dialog.appendChild(paragraph)
    dialog.appendChild(purchase)
    document.body.appendChild(dialog)
    dialog.showModal()
  }
})
```

```css
.dialog-box {
  position: absolute: top:100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-cars"></div>
```